# hide an html div for some devices with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use from `bootstrap 3`, a have a div, i want to show this in only XS and LG devices. how I can do this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the responsive utility classes...

```
<div class="visible-lg hidden-md hidden-sm visible-xs">visible large and xs</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/78724